# UIView Animation, Transforming layer.shadowPath

Tags: iphone, ios

I created a UIImageView that has a custom shadowPath.  This view will be moved left and right across the screen, but I need the shadowPath to have a different transformation than the image layer itself.  Is this possible? Moving the image itself works, and the shadow moves as well when I do the following:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
im.center = location;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But if I try to add a layer transformation before "commitAnimations", the shadow will simply take on that property right away, for example:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
im.center = location;
im.layer.shadowPath = [self createPerspectiveShadow:im]; //this will not animate
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

So, my question is, is there a way to recalculate a shadow during the animation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIView` animations don’t always allow you to animate `CALayer` attributes; try using a `CABasicAnimation` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, a CABasicAnimation probably won't cut it because I have to recalculate the entire shadow path.  CABasicAnimation.fromValue and .toValue require NSNumbers, and I can't pass a CGPathRef to them instead.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Hmm, that’s a tough one. You may be better off setting up an `NSTimer` to fire once every 1/60th of a second, then updating the position of the shadow programmatically. Sucks, but it’ll work…

Comment: I was afraid this was going to come up :) Oh well, I was hoping for a quicker, easier solution. Anyway, thanks for your input Jeff (I'll mark your answer in a day or two...)

Comment: A bit late but you can definitely animate paths with CABasicAnimation. `fromValue` and `toValue` are `id`, so just do a `(__bridge id)` on the `CGPathRef`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a CGPathREf to the toValue

```
theAnimation.toValue = (id)[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:newRect].CGPath;
```

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924734/animating-calayers-shadowpath-property)